# Java: Merge two hashmaps?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have tried to implement my own merge function but it is getting more and more complicated and have more and more error. I was thinking maybe Java already have this function since it seems like a common development problem.

Imagine I have two `HashMaps<String, int>`:

```
 HM1.put(foo,1)
 HM1.put(bar,1)

 HM2.put(foo,1)
 HM2.put(main,1)
```

When they are merged, the new HM2 will be something like this:

```
 [foo: 2]
 [bar, 1]
 [main,1]
```

Comment: it is a bit different since mine only wants HM1 to be added to HM2 instead of creating a new HashMap also HM1 may have null value that which is combined into HM2, using the linked provided above will run into NullPointerException

Comment: @Balasubramanian Not a duplicate. The OP wants to sum values for the same keys, not just merge maps.

Comment: Is it OK to merge the second map into the first, so the first contains the result (instead of creating a new map)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the second map and update HM1 dynamically:

```
HM2.entrySet()
   .forEach(entry -> HM1.compute(
            entry.getKey(),
            (key, value) -> value == null ? 
                            entry.getValue() : 
                            entry.getValue() + value));
```

**EDIT**:
Better use `.merge` (suggested by lexicore in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460205/java-merge-two-hashmaps/50460526?noredirect=1#comment87934212_50460526)), which avoids unnecessary runs of the compute function for absent keys:

```
HM2.entrySet()
   .forEach(entry -> HM1.merge(
            entry.getKey(),
            entry.getValue(),
            (key, value) -> entry.getValue()   + value));
```

Either of the above will update `HM1` to have the final result.

```
System.out.println(HM1);
```

Outpus:

```
{bar=1, foo=2, main=1}
```

Comment: Better `HM1.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), (k, v) -> entry.getValue() + v)`.

Comment: @lexicore Absolutely agreed

Comment: combined with lexicore's comment, the code above worked great. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stream/collector-based solution. It turns maps into streams of entries, concatenates them and then collects into a map, using entry keys as keys and summing values as `int`s.

```
    Map<String, Integer> HM1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> HM2 = new HashMap<>();
    HM1.put("foo", 1);
    HM1.put("bar", 1);

    HM2.put("foo", 1);
    HM2.put("main", 1);

    Map<String, Integer> result = Stream
        .concat(HM1.entrySet().stream(), HM2.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Answer (score 0):

hope, this will help you

```
Set<String> keySet=hashMap1.keySet();

for(String str: keySet){
    int value=hashMap1.get(str);
    if(hashMap2.containsKey(str)){
        hashMap2.put(str, hashMap2.get(str)+value);
    }
    else{
        hashMap2.put(str, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You read from the map too much. Use `entrySet` to avoid unnecessary `get`s from `HM1` and `merge` or `compute` to avoid unnecessary `get`s from `HM1`. Every time you see `containsKey`/`get` or `put` combo, this can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

`Map.merge()`, as used above, is wrong. Remapping function there should be

```
(oldvalue, newvalue) -> oldvalue + newvalue
```

Interestingly enough, the original author mistook `2 * 1`, as implemented by him, for `1 + 1`. Hey, the result is what I want, right? Lesson learnt, 1 is not a good test value.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is by using the [toMap Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)), which is defined to take a merge function:

```
var hm1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hm1.put("foo",1);
hm1.put("bar",2);
var hm2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hm2.put("foo",4);
hm2.put("baz",8);
var v = Stream.of(hm1, hm2)
    .map(Map::entrySet)
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,   // key mapper
            Map.Entry::getValue, // value mapper
            Integer::sum         // merge function
        )
    );
System.out.println(v);
```

**Output:**

> {bar=2, foo=5, baz=8}

Answer (score 0):

```java
HM1.forEach((k, v) -> 
HM2.merge(k, v, (key, value) -> v + value));
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by eexplaining how/why it solves the asker's problem.