# TestOutputTopic.readKeyValuesToMap() removes messages from tested topic. How to do intermediate assertions during the test?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit, apache-kafka-streams

While using `TopologyTestDriver` I want to test my stream and do assrtions on intermediate state between incoming messages. But after using `TestOutputTopic.readKeyValuesToMap()` tested topic is cleared. How to "peek" and do assertions between messages?

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Grouped;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.test.TestRecord;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Properties;

public class AggregationTest {

    private static TestInputTopic<String, String> inputTopic;
    private static TestOutputTopic<String, String> outputTopic;
    private static TopologyTestDriver testDriver;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup() {
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        builder
                .stream("inputTopic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .toTable(Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .groupBy(
                        KeyValue::pair,
                        Grouped.with("group-by-internal", Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .aggregate(
                        () -> "",
                        (key, incomingMessage, existingMessage) -> incomingMessage + " " + existingMessage,
                        (key, incomingMessage, existingMessage) -> existingMessage
                ).toStream().to("outputTopic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(builder.build(), new Properties() {{
            put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test");
            put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
            put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
            put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
            put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "/tmp/kafka-streams");
        }});

        inputTopic = testDriver.createInputTopic("inputTopic", Serdes.String().serializer(), Serdes.String().serializer());
        outputTopic = testDriver.createOutputTopic("outputTopic", Serdes.String().deserializer(), Serdes.String().deserializer());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAggregation() {
        TestRecord<String, String> message1 = new TestRecord<>( "Key1", "Value1");
        TestRecord<String, String> message2 = new TestRecord<>( "Key2", "Value2");
        TestRecord<String, String> message3 = new TestRecord<>( "Key1", "Value3");

        inputTopic.pipeInput(message1);
        inputTopic.pipeInput(message2);
        var outputMap = outputTopic.readKeyValuesToMap();
        System.out.println(outputMap); // {Key2=Value2 , Key1=Value1 }
        // Assert that message1 and message2 was not effected

        inputTopic.pipeInput(message3);

        var outputMap2 = outputTopic.readKeyValuesToMap();
        System.out.println(outputMap2); // {Key1=Value3 Value1 } // where message with Key2 disappeared?
        // How to assert that message3 was merged with message1, but message2 was not effected?
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDown() {
        testDriver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than reassign your outputMap variable, why not add into the same map?

Comment: under the hood I'm testing groupBy and aggregation, so message3 updates message1 and message2. In that case I can't assert message1 and message2, because they are lost after intermediate assertion. If I will leave them in the map, they will only have old state which was before message3.

Comment: The variable references named `message1` and `message2` are not lost. Please show a [mcve] of your assertions... Also, that doesn't really address my comment of [merge the maps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50460526/2308683) rather than use the same instance

Comment: Sure, I'm going to update my question.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I have updated my question with full working example. And while I was writing this, I realized that you are right and I need to merge those maps and last map represents only latest changed messages.. I expected readKeyValuesToMap() always create full picture after using it. This kind of functionality is a bit pain and requires boiler plate code for every lib user imho. Please add your comment as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: Even if you merged the maps, it would exhibit the same behavior, no? The latest map keys would override the previous values.

Comment: Second map doesnt contain message with key “Key2” so after merge i will see full representation. Only “Key1” with old state will be overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JavaDoc](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/TestOutputTopic.html#readKeyValuesToMap--) indicates it should return the full, latest state of the topic (are you sure a tombstone event wasn't introduced, somehow?), so I am not sure why it would disappear.

If you want to aggregate the state of both maps, you can [merge them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50460526/2308683) rather than re-assign the previous reference, but that would fix the test, not necessarily actual runtime behavior...

You may want to revisit your aggregate function. `Key2` has no `existingMessage` when it is originally incoming. Therefore, you've returned `null` there, and it would not exist in the map output. Only value you'd have is therefore `Value3 Value1`

Try this for instances where you only expect one value

```
(key, incomingMessage, existingMessage) -> existingMessage == null ? incomingMessage : existingMessage
```

Comment: existing message is never null, because empty string is created instead of null (see example aggregate method first parameter ‘ () -> "" ‘. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like java doc is a bit misleading, i reproduced this multiple times, pretty sure it’s the way how it works.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:
`readKeyValuesToMap`:
"Read output to map. If the result is considered a stream, you can use `readRecordsToList()` instead."

The Map depict the table only containing the latest value per key. What you want is the stream of data records.

Link: https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/TestOutputTopic.html#readKeyValuesToMap-- 
(PS sorry for the incomplete answer, I can not comment yet.)